# Writing variables defined in site.pp file to file

Tags: puppet-enterprise

On my puppet master I have a `site.pp` file that defines the content of some certificates like so ...

```
$swift_cert_content = '
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
blhablhadfblhablah...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
'
```

... and I want to write the value of `$swift_cert_content` to the file `/tmp/swift_cert` on my puppet master.  I have tried this ...

```
# cat create_cert_files.pp 
class create_cert_files (
  $swift_cert_content = $::swift_cert_content,
) {
  file { '/tmp/swift_cert':
    ensure => "file",
    content => $swift_cert_content,
  } 
}

class { 'create_cert_files': }
```

... and I execute this like so ...

```
# puppet apply create_cert_files.pp 
Notice: Compiled catalog for osc-ppt-001.example.com in environment production in 0.16 seconds
Notice: /Stage[main]/Create_cert_files/File[/tmp/swift_cert]/ensure: created
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.31 seconds
```

... but the file is empty:

```
# ls -l /tmp/swift_cert 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Aug 26 14:55 /tmp/swift_cert
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot that when one uses `puppet apply` puppet ignores the site.pp file so I need to do something like this:

```
# cat /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/manifests/site.pp create_cert_files.pp > runit.pp
# puppet apply runit.pp
```